# Is there an uppercase letter that has two lowercase alternatives?

Tags: unicode, uppercase, lowercase

Are there any two characters `ch1`, `ch2`, `ch1 <> ch2`, and `ch1` and `ch2` are lowercase letters, where `uppercase(ch1) == uppercase(ch2)`? Is there actually such a character in Unicode?

A follow-up question is: For any `ch` that's a lowercase letter, is the following expression always true?

```
ch == lowercase(uppercase(ch))
```

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of those charactes, but what makes this even more complicated is that the result of lowercase() and uppercase() depends on the locale you use. See [doted and dotless I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I).

Comment: This question *might* just be idle curiosity, but maybe it isn't. Is there an underlying problem that you're trying to solve? Because if there is, there's a good chance that it already has a solution.

Comment: @JoachimSauer My underlying problem is that I was considering a particular algorithm for resolving case-insensitive references to case-sensitive identifiers. The above assumption would be important, but now I see I can't use it.

Comment: you can build a `ColationKey` using a `Collator` with the correct locale and strength. `CollationKeys` are very quick to compare because they just do binary comparison. You can pre-build the `CollationKey`s for all your identifiers and for lookup you make one from the input parameter using the same `Collator`. Note that this still requires a *specfic* locale to work correctly (which you can't really ignore, since case folding rules differ by locale).

Comment: @JoachimSauer My issue is different. Let's stick to the question, I think it's interesting in general.

Comment: An old, but interesting discussion, casing (uppercasing, lowercasing)  are not case-insensitive, for that you need to use case folding instead. Bur casefolding is a building block, Unicode specifies four mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

Did a quick test in Java:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (char ch1 = 0; ch1 < 65534; ch1++) {
        if (!isLetter(ch1) || !isLowerCase(ch1)) {
            continue;
        }
        String s1 = "" + ch1;
        for (char ch2 = (char) (ch1 + 1); ch2 < 65535; ch2++) {
            if (!isLetter(ch2) || !isLowerCase(ch2)) {
                continue;
            }
            String s2 = "" + ch2;
            if (s1.toUpperCase(Locale.US).equals(s2.toUpperCase(Locale.US))) {
                System.out.println("ch1=" + ch1 + " (" + (int) ch1 + "), ch2=" + ch2 + " (" + (int) ch2 + ")");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
ch1=i (105), ch2=ı (305)
ch1=s (115), ch2=ſ (383)
ch1=µ (181), ch2=μ (956)
ch1=ΐ (912), ch2=ΐ (8147)
ch1=ΰ (944), ch2=ΰ (8163)
ch1=β (946), ch2=ϐ (976)
ch1=ε (949), ch2=ϵ (1013)
ch1=θ (952), ch2=ϑ (977)
ch1=ι (953), ch2=ι (8126)
ch1=κ (954), ch2=ϰ (1008)
ch1=π (960), ch2=ϖ (982)
ch1=ρ (961), ch2=ϱ (1009)
ch1=ς (962), ch2=σ (963)
ch1=φ (966), ch2=ϕ (981)
ch1=в (1074), ch2=ᲀ (7296)
ch1=д (1076), ch2=ᲁ (7297)
ch1=о (1086), ch2=ᲂ (7298)
ch1=с (1089), ch2=ᲃ (7299)
ch1=т (1090), ch2=ᲄ (7300)
ch1=т (1090), ch2=ᲅ (7301)
ch1=ъ (1098), ch2=ᲆ (7302)
ch1=ѣ (1123), ch2=ᲇ (7303)
ch1=ᲄ (7300), ch2=ᲅ (7301)
ch1=ᲈ (7304), ch2=ꙋ (42571)
ch1=ṡ (7777), ch2=ẛ (7835)
ch1=ﬅ (64261), ch2=ﬆ (64262)
```

So the answer is: yes, there are distinct characters that have the same upper-case representation.

Comment: Which is maybe not what it is asked.

Answer (score 0):

Upper, title, and lower cases are locale-specific, and so in different locales you may have different lower case letter (e.g. French upper cases may lose accents).

But Unicode defines also a standard way to convert to upper case or to lower case, and with an exception for Turkish languages, which may have different rules (marked with `T` in the `CaseFolding.txt` Unicode database, and further special cases for Turkish, Greek, and Lithuanian, in `SpecialCasing.txt`).

For most cases, you have a unique way to convert lower to upper (and the contrary), but see SIGN KELVIN which maps with K and other signs which use the same glyphs as other letters (that should go away, if you remove compatibility characters with a normalization).

One case is the Greek Sigma letter. There is only one in upper case, but you may use two different in lower case, depending on whether it is at the end of a word.

You will find more information in the Unicode document about Unicode database: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Casemapping and in the Unicode standard (linked in the document, as well the two files I named above).

Note: some characters increase the number of code points, so when converting back, one should check the longest match.